# Trying to use \MakePerPage{footnote} kills the build of my LaTeX doc

Tags: footnotes, labels, makefile

The standard LaTeX footnote behavior is to mark footnotes using superscript numbers. I can't use that, since all of my citations are superscript numbers. What I'd like is for my footnotes to be marked with symbols, and for the set of symbols to reset on each page (eg the first footnote on a page should always be marked with `*`). To make this happen I added the following to one of my `.sty` files:

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

However, these lines break my build. When I run the `make` command and my `makefile` gets to the `pdflatex` step, every footnote after the 7th one now raises an error of the form:

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.502 ... the topic of enhanced sampling\footnote{
                                                  Technically, Kahn et al., ...
```

If I comment out those lines, everything builds just fine, though of course then the footnotes are wrong. If I comment out just the `\MakePerPage{footnote}`, then errors don't begin until after the 8th footnote. Either way, it seems like the `\MakePerPage{footnote}` directive is being ignored, and that LaTeX is running out of footnote symbols.

I've used the above approach to get symbol footnotes in previous projects. The difference seems to be that before I was writing/building my docs using Texpad, whereas now I have a manual `makefile` build. So obviously there's something wrong with/missing from my `makefile`. Here's what the contents of the `makefile` look like:

```
fname=main
${fname}.pdf: ${fname}.tex \
    thesis_header.tex \
    abstract/abstract.tex \
    committee/committee.tex \
    acknowledgments/acknowledgments.tex \
    thesis_intro/thesis_intro.tex \
    bib/thesis_intro.bib \
    eces_chapter/error_control_of_enhanced_sampling.tex \
    bib/error_control_of_enhanced_sampling.bib \
    conclusion_chapter/conclusion_chapter.tex
    if [ -e ${fname}.aux ]; \
    then \
    rm ${fname}.aux; \
    fi;
    pdflatex ${fname}
    bibtex ${fname}
    bibtex ${fname}1-blx
    bibtex ${fname}2-blx
    # Add more if you have more chapters
    pdflatex ${fname}
    pdflatex ${fname}
    cp ${fname}.pdf PhD_Thesis.pdf
    open PhD_Thesis.pdf
clean:
    ...
open:
    open ${fname}.pdf
edit:
    open ${fname}.tex
```

All of the footnote errors occur during the first call to `pdflatex`. At the end of that first call to `pdflatex`, an (incomplete) pdf is produced, and the build halts with another error message:

```
make: *** [main.pdf] Error 1
```

This project is a PhD thesis, so I'm working off a [template (written by another student a few years ago)](https://github.com/weitzner/jhu-thesis-template) that meets my school/library's formatting requirements (basically, some weird wide margins + the output has to be PDF/A). I didn't write the `makefile`, nor do I particularly understand it, I just substituted the `.tex`/`.bib` filenames with my own. The `makefile` doesn't resemble other example LaTeX `makefile`'s that I was able to find on the internet, so I'm at a loss as how to fix it. Anyone familiar enough with the `perpage` package and/or similar footnote issues who can point me in the right direction?

If you want more details, the entire set of sources for my thesis are in a [public repo here](https://github.com/telamonian/jhu-thesis-template).

Comment: Odd that you get an error for 7th I'd expect it to be 9th, the standard fnsymbol counter style only has 9 symbols, although you can easily extend it.

Comment: it would be simpler to answer if you had posted a small but complete document with 7 footnotes on a page that gave the error (none of the makefile is related to the error message)

Comment: The 7th one works, while the 8th one has the error. Looking through the incomplete pdf output it seems like somehow the `*` is getting skipped, and the first footnote is using the `†` symbol.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know the problem has something to do with the `makefile`, at least. All of the info I've found on `\MakePerPage{footnote}` suggest that it requires two passes of `pdflatex` to work correctly. Is there some way to just make the `makefile` power through and do the second pass instead of halting on error? Also, I'll see if I can create the same error with just a single `.tex` file alongside a `makefile`.

Comment: you shouldn't get an error

Comment: I am fairly sure I've never had 7 footnotes in a document never mind on a page:-)

Comment: If I had my way all of my papers would be nothing but a single paragraph with 80 footnotes. Sadly, in reality they're not all on one page (I think the most is two). It would still be nice to reset to `*` on each, page, so I don't have to break out the exotica like the double-double dagger `‡‡`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the make file. It is caused by the fact that LaTeX processes the input *past* the end of a page (for example, up to the end of the current paragraph) before it knows there *is* a page full of text, so the on the first pass through the document you have already processed some footnotes that will eventually end up on page 2 before `makeperpage` "knows" they are not all on page 1.

`makeperpage` works fine with numbered footnotes, because it is very unlikely to run out of numbers during the first pass through the document!

During the first pass, `makeperpage` remembers where the page breaks actually were, and uses that information to produce the correct footnote symbols on the second pass.

A brute force way to fix this is just to turn the error message into a warning. Insert the following into the preamble of your `.tex` input file, before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\@ctrerr{%
  \@latex@warning{Counter too large}}
\makeatother
```

The "standard" version of LaTeX uses `\@latex@error` not `\@latex@warning` here.

Comment: Haha, awesome. Thank you. Latex: so much spaghetti that for the first time silencing an error message was the actually correct fix for an error.

Answer (score 2):

the expected behaviour is to get an error on the 10th, some code you have not shown is presumably using two footnotes somewhere.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\begin{document}

1\footnote{zz}
2\footnote{zz}
3\footnote{zz}
4\footnote{zz}
5\footnote{zz}
6\footnote{zz}
7\footnote{zz}
8\footnote{zz}
9\footnote{zz}
10\footnote{zz}
11\footnote{zz}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 10\footnote{
                 zz}
?
```

However `fnsymbol` is a trivial macro that can easily be extended, the default definition is

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or \TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
   \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
   \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
   \TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection\or
   \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
   \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
   \TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\else
   \@ctrerr \fi
}%
```

so you could use

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or
   \TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
   \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
   \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
   \TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection\or
   \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
   \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
   \TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textsection\textsection}{\mathsection\mathsection}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textbardbl\textbardbl}{\|\|}\else
   \@ctrerr \fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

1\footnote{zz}
2\footnote{zz}
3\footnote{zz}
4\footnote{zz}
5\footnote{zz}
6\footnote{zz}
7\footnote{zz}
8\footnote{zz}
9\footnote{zz}
10\footnote{zz}
11\footnote{zz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just doubled up characters here but of course you can use any symbols that you have available.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was wondering how to extend the set of symbols. However, alephzero directly addresses the issue of making `perpage` correctly reset the symbols on each page, so I had to go with his answer.

Comment: @tel I can probably survive without the points:-)

Comment: if you change the final `\@ctrerr` by `\arabic{#1}` then it will use numbers when it runs out of symbols and never give an error. @tel